# $L^2$ bound on solution of PDE in terms of $L^2$ norm of initial value

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces, elliptic-pde

Let $u \in H^1((0,T)\times S)$ be the unique solution of 
$$u_{tt} + \Delta u =0$$
$$u|_{t=0}= u_0$$
$$u|_{t=T}=0$$
where $u_0 \in H^{\frac 12}(S)$ and $S$ is some Euclidean hypersurface without boundary (eg. unit sphere). The weak formulation satisfied is
$$\int_0^T\int_S u_tv_t + \nabla u \nabla v = 0$$
for each $v \in H^1((0,T)\times S)$ such that $v|_{t=0}=v|_{t=T}=0$.

---

Is it possible to obtain the following bound:
$$\lVert u \rVert_{L^2((0,T)\times S)} \leq C\lVert{u_0}\rVert_{L^2(S)}?$$
So I want a bound on the $L^2$ norm involving only the $L^2$ of the initial data, not the full $H^{\frac 12}$ norm.

Comment: Yes, and much more than this is known. Try a literature search with keywords "Dirichlet problem" and "L2 data."